# ¿Como combinar una celda de una tabla verticalmente?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera saber como puedo combinar una celda verticalmente de mi tabla HTML, he investigado que con un rowspan, pero el problema que yo lo hago con un foreach y el numero de registros varea, al hacer la consulta puede traer solo 3 registros o 10 dependiendo los registros que existan, quisiera que la primer columna viniera combinada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi codigo de mi tabla, igual uso JavaScript

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tbRecetas5">
                        <thead style="background-color: #1359A1; color: #ffffff">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Dirección
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Código EAN
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Descripción de Medicamento
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Unidades
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id="tbodyRecetas">
                            @if (ViewBag.Asignar.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.Asignar)
                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span id="idDireccion"></span></td>
                                        <td>@item.CodigoEAN</td>
                                        <td>@item.DescripcionMedicamento</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">@item.Unidades</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <template>
                                    <p class="alert alert-info">No se encontraron registros</p>
                                </template>}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen para saber que resultado esperas

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes el contador de registros encontrados, úsalo para combinar las celdas:

```
<td rowspan="@ViewBag.Asignar.Count">Contenido de la celda</td>
```